# Use of expectation propagation for inference

Tags: bayesian, inference, approximation

I have a PGM as described by the attached diagram.

[image: Graphical model]

$y$ is observed and I want to infer the joint posterior distribution as given by $P(w,\lambda, \phi |y)$. Distribution on $w$ is modelled using a multivariate 0 mean with a covariance structure. $\lambda$ needs to be inferred from the data and the prior on it is modelled using a gamma distribution with scale and shape parameters $s_0$ and $C_0$. The noise variance $\phi$ also needs to be estimated and its prior is also modelled using a Gamma distribution with parameters $a_0$ and $b_0$

I have been looking at using Expectation Propagation to perform this approximate inference on this model. As I understand, EP works by minimising the KL divergence between the true posterior and the approximated distributions.

So, my questions are:

1: Can I use EP in such a case?

2: Can someone help me understand what objective function I need to design in this model? As far as I can tell, the EP will approximate the try posterior by independent distributions from the exponential family. So,

$P(w,\lambda, \phi)  \approx q(w) q(\lambda) q(\phi)$

And now do we minimise the KL divergence between true p and q's? I am really having trouble understanding this setup and would be really grateful if someone can help me understand where and how to start!

Any help/pointer/comments will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use EP for this.  Start by writing the model as a factor graph.  For each edge of the factor graph, there will be two messages: one from the variable to the factor and another from the factor to the variable.  EP provides a formula for each message in terms of the surrounding messages.  This gives a system of equations that you iterate until convergence.  Once the messages have converged, you compute the marginal distributions from them.  See the paper [Divergence measures and message passing](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=67425) for details.  There is a free software library called [Infer.NET](http://research.microsoft.com/infernet) that implements EP message updates for many different factor types.  You provide it with a factor graph and it generates code with the message updates.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I guess the answer cannot come from a better source! Also, can the different approximating distributions for the variables be from different distributions (gamma, multivariate normal etc.) as long as they are from the exponential family?

Comment: Yes, you can use different exponential families to approximate the marginal for different variables.  You only need all messages into a variable to have the same type, so that they can be multiplied together to get the marginal.